# File search with MS Graph SDK does not work

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have coded a webhook for One-Drive according to these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/) which also works but now I have the following problem:

I would like to search for a file with the Graph SDK(ASP.Net Core and C#), with Postman this also works as desired.

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/drive/root/search(q='Filename')
```

But I just can't get it to work with the SDK.

```
 private async Task<IDriveItemSearchCollectionPage> SearchFiles(GraphServiceClient graphClient){
   var search = await graphClient.Users["User-iD"].Drive.Root
     .Search("Filename")
     .Request()
     .GetAsync();
    
     return search;
 }
```

And the associated iterator:

```
 private void PrintFiles(IDriveItemSearchCollectionPage files) {

        foreach(var file in files) {
          var message = $"File: {file.Name}, Id: {file.Id}";

          Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: When you do this search function in the SDK does it also search folders shared with you?

Comment: I think it depends, if you have all permissions in the system you can search everything, if you have restricted permissions then only the shared ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so crazy, I've been looking for a solution for days and nothing worked, and now it works even though **I haven't changed anything in my code.**