# Do I have to be logged in to search files in MS Graph?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I have already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782312/file-search-with-ms-graph-sdk-does-not-work) about searching files(One Drive DataItems) in MS Graph and wanted to ask can I also start a search without being logged in ?

So if I create a daemon(or Background-Service) as shown in the webhook with MS Graph [exercise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/) from Microsoft ?

Or does the search only work when a user is logged in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't have to log in, so it also works as a daemon service.